# magento remove Default cms Pages

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

got a simple question.
I have the problem that the header of magento returns 404. The reason for this is simple, I deactivated the default template Home Page (it still exists) and my Shop cannot find this template logically, but instead of not loading this he returns 404 in my head and my template I made is shown ... so everything works fine except the HTTP Status 404 in my head.

The reason why I don't use a simple cms page for my index is also simple, I cannot build my screen-design in this column layout for my index.

What I want: Remove the need for a index cms page, so he doesn't return a senseless 404 in my head.

And at least I got my reputation score of 10, thanks.

Here we can see my Http header. The black bar is just the index file (the missing cms page)
[image: Here we can see my Http header. The black bar is just the index file (the missing cms page)]

This is the option we want to remove
[image: This is the option we want to remove]

Comment: It shouldn't be impossible for you to build your homepage using a CMS page, knowing that you can actually change their column layout and lots of other things. What's preventing you from doing so at the moment ?

Comment: Actually I don't made this I just have to fix it. And the hole layout is done so fare. My fear is that search engines wont find the shop because its returning 404. I have to accept the fact that we don't use a cms page in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your homepage is getting rendered like it should, to get rid of the 404 status you can override the `Mage_Cms_IndexController` controller (check this link  :http://prattski.com/2010/06/24/magento-overriding-core-files-blocks-models-resources-controllers/), and modify its `defaultIndexAction()` method like below :

```
public function defaultIndexAction()
{
    // $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','404 Not Found');
    // $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Status','404 File not found');

    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Comment: Hey,
first of all thanks for your answer.
I was at this point already ... I mean this method and removed these lines. My thoughts are just: In the case some resources are missing, this method will never return an error again.

To overwrite the magento core files is risky.

Comment: .... But it also seems like this method is used just for this case ...

jep made a little test ... it is just used in the case of a fallback

well I try it

Comment: Yes it's only used when there is no default CMS page to render, else other 404 are handled by `noRouteAction()` (and `defaultNoRouteAction()` if there is no default 404 page)

Comment: Okay thanks again. I did it in this way, but actually it is a dirty hack. At least I fixed a dirty hack with a dirty hack ... hacks are disappointing